# Writing sql query that relate two screens

Tags: java, sql, database, eclipse, oracle

Good morning . I have a question . I have two screens in my program one is check in that will have special field (check no).The other screen is check out. It also have check no . I want to write a query that relate the check in with check out by using the check no and save it in one row in database . i wrote :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    while(textField.getText()==Securityoffcheck.getnumber())
    {
        try{    
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy  HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
                String sql = "INSERT INTO RECORD(CHECK_OUT)VALUES(?)";
                PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(12, timeStamp);
                pst.execute();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
    }
  }
});
```

but nothing happen .

Answer (score 1):

Check your parameter index in `pst.setString(12, ...)`. For your SQL statement `INSERT INTO RECORD(CHECK_OUT) VALUES(?)` you should set the parameter index to 1.

Comment: but the column that i want ti insert into is column number 12 ?

Comment: @razansaad The index is based on the number of bind variables (? in the statement), not on table columns.

Comment: The first argument of `setString` is not the column number but the parameter index (1 for the first `?` placeholder, 2 for the second, etc). This document should explain the usage: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html